# Regex - Always remove a specific set of characters in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to create a regex that always removes the following characters in a string:

`\ / : * ? " < > |`

I have a string like the following:

`const str = 't""h<i"|s< i/??||/s::>: **a? t:|:e>>s\\t*///';`

When I use `replace()` like the following:

`const sanitize = str.replace(/\*|:|\/|"|\?|\\|<|>|\|/g,'');`

I get the following:

`"this is a test"`

This is the desired result. The only time this *doesn't* work is if there is a **single** backslash `\` in front of the first letter of a word -- it will then also remove the first letter of that word. Example:

`const str = 't\his is a \test';`

`const sanitize = str.replace(/\*|:|\/|"|\?|\\|<|>|\|/g,'');`

Will result in:

`"this is a  est"`

How do I remove all backslashes `\` without also removing a whitelisted character that happens to be next to the removed blackslash?

https://jsbin.com/jequxugoka/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `String.raw` to make it so the single backslashes are escaped into double backslashes:

```js
const str = String.raw`t\his is a \test`;

const sanitize = str.replace(/\*|:|\/|"|\?|\\|<|>|\|/g,'');

console.log(sanitize);
```